# Terraform external data source as input to provider

Tags: terraform

I have a simple script that should return the connection string for a database that I can then use as input parameters for a postgres provider.

I am reading the credentials from the AWS Secrets Manager using a smallish bash script. The script works and returns JSON in a suitable format.

The first time I tested my script, it worked! Well, not exactly - the username was wrong. I fixed my script to return the correct username, but terraform continued to use the old username

The terraform plan:

```
provider "postgresql" {
    alias    = "db_admin"
    host     = "${data.external.root_password.result.host}"
    sslmode  = "disable"
    port     = 5432
    database = "postgres"
    username = "${data.external.root_password.result.username}"
    password = "${data.external.root_password.result.password}"
}

data "external" "root_password" {
    program = ["bash", "${path.module}/get_root_password.sh"]

    query = {
        secret_name = "${var.root_password_name}"
        assume_role = "${terraform.workspace}"
    }
}
```

And the bash script:

```
    #!/bin/bash

    set -e

    # This is a simplified version of the script for debugging purposes
    # The first version had username = martin, but then got changed to root
    echo {\"password\": \"not_the_password\", \"host\": \"some_db\", \"username\": \"root\"}
```

The output of terraform is as follows (note the user name is martin not root):

```
Error: Error refreshing state: 1 error(s) occurred:

* module.db_roles.provider.postgresql.db_admin: Error initializing PostgreSQL client: error detecting capabilities: error PostgreSQL version: pq: password authentication failed for user "martin"
```

The old value must be cached somewhere... but I've tried looking everywhere, with no luck. The other thing I've noticed is the plan seems to be initializing the postgres provider before the external data has been run. Could that be the case? It still wouldn't answer where the old value is coming from!

Comment: Have you checked the state file to make sure that username isn't cached in there?

Comment: Yes, I checked that - its not in there. That would be strange if it was - I am just planning at this stage.

Comment: Why not just use the [aws_secretsmanager_secret_version](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/secretsmanager_secret_version.html) data source as an input rather than some shell script?

Comment: It's possible that `terraform init` has cached your script's output in the `.terraform` directory so if you blow that away and re-init, you might have the desired outcome using the external data source.